# Existence of a Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis

If Z is a normal, second countable space and B is an open subset of Z, is it true that there is some continuous $f: Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in B$, but $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x$ not in $B$?

I'm attempting to construct such an $f$ piecewise, but struggling when it comes to continuity...

Comment: By $Z$ do you mean the integers set?

Comment: I think $X$ and $Z$ must be the same thing.

Comment: Apologies for the mistype. I've just fixed it.

Comment: If it's true, you probably want to use Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: Right, so since the space is Normal, I could select two arbitrary disjoint open sets, (say $A$ and $B$) and define a function $f(a) = 0$ for $a \in A$ and $f(b) = 1$ for $b \in B$ by Urysohn's Lemma. However, I'm struggling to see how I can make $f(x)=0 $ for all $x$ not in this set $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Z$ is normal and second-countable, so $Z$ is metrizable. (By Urysohn's metrization theorem.) So there exists metric $d$ such that $d$ induce topology of $Z$. Let define $$f(x) := d(x,B^C),$$
then $f$ is desired function. (note that $d(x,A)=\inf _{y\in A}d(x,y)$.)

---

*Proof of continuity of $f$:* By definition of $f$, we get
$$f(x)\le d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$
for all $z\in A$. Take infimum both side of this inequality then we get
$$f(x)\le d(x,y)+f(y)$$
Therefore
$$f(x)-f(y)\le d(x,y)$$
and
$$f(y)-f(x)\le d(y,x)=d(x,y)$$
thus we get
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le d(x,y).$$

Comment: Is it true that this $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @user73881 I added the proof of continuity of $f$.